# How to find the number of a specific element in an arraylist in Java (blueJ)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, size, bluej

I have and array list and in that array list there are 5 elements called pound and 3 called penny. How can I calculate the number of times that pound occurs in the array list

Answer (score 1):

This method should do it.

```
public int getNrPound(String[] arr) {
  int nrPound = 0;
  for (String string : arr) {
    if (string.equals("pound"))
      nrPound++;
  }
  return nrPound;
}
```

The answer is similar to previous ones but the for loop iterates through each element of the array instead of getting each element by index. The advantages are you do not need to know that an array in Java is zero based and it is shorter and easier to read. This coding style should make your code less error prone.

Comment: always explain why this answer is the best, to improve answer quality :)

Comment: @W1ll1amvl Thanks, I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

No specification was added to your question, so my code does not necessarily meet your criteria.

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++) {
    counter = (myArrayList.get(i).equals("pound")) ? (counter + 1) : (counter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if("pound".equals(array[i]))
    count++;
}
```